# Javascript: Confuse about object property access

Tags: javascript, object

Here is a object I build：

```
var Obj = {
    foo: {
        foo: function () {
            return this.bar;
        },
        bar: "bar"
    },
    bar: "BAR"
}

console.log(Obj.foo.foo());
```

The `Obj.foo.foo` method can only access the `Obj.foo.bar` property's value, or the property of its owner `Obj.foo`. Can it access the `Obj.bar`'s value? How?

Comment: it can access it using Obj.bar

Comment: In `x.method()`, the `this` in the method is `x`. So, for `Obj.foo.foo()`, `this` inside is `Obj.foo` (and `Obj.bar` is *not* accessible without using `Obj`).

Comment: "Does it can access" conveys no meaning according to the rules of the English language. If you are curious whether or not the function can access the aforementioned value, write "can it access ...?".

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, and yet - everyone somehow knew what the OP had in mind ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Scope scope and scope

Javascript is a fun language. And one of the realy cool things is the binding of this.

this is defined on function call. So depending on how you call a method. this can change. You can even change it on the fly. Given the following objects:

```
var Obj = {
    foo: {
        myFunc: function () {
            return this.bar;
        },
        bar: "bar"
    },
    bar: "BAR"
}

var Obj2 = {
    foo: {
        bar: "foobar"
    },
    bar: "FOOBAR"
}
```

we can have some fun:

```
Obj.foo.myFunc(); // "bar"
```

but we could use call the method binding a different scope

```
Obj.foo.myFunc.call(Obj); // "BAR"
```

Here Obj is bound to this.

We can even bind completly different objects:

```
Obj.foo.myFunc.call(Obj2); // "FOOBAR"
Obj.foo.myFunc.call(Obj2.foo); // "foobar"
```

or call it ouside of it's scope:

```
var bar = "something completly different";
var func = Obj.foo.myFunc;
func(); // "something completly different"
```

so much fun :)

Comment: The question was 'is there a way to access "owner" object'.

Comment: And I explained JS Scopes. That the "owner" is bound on invocation. And that you can change "owner" by using the call method.

Comment: So you described one way of accessing `Obj.bar` in `Obj.foo.myFunc()`.  Can you elaborate on how my answer is wrong?

Comment: And for the record, the concept of "owner" does not exist in Javascript. Using `Function.prototype.call` changes the value of `this`. Using your solution, how do access 'Obj.foo.bar' in `Obj.foo.foo()` if you bind `this` to `Obj` ? :)

Comment: this.foo.bar does the job really well

Comment: true, the last question was not exactly my best try :) It does not however change my point - whether it's `Obj`, `this` or `that` - you DO need a reference do the object to access its properties, and there are no "owners" in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a function scope holding the needed reference:

```
var Obj = (function() {
 var that = this;
 return  {
  foo: {
    foo: function () {
     return that.bar;
    },
    bar: "bar"
  },
  bar: "BAR"
})();
```

I think this should work..

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way to access "parent" reference - there is no such concept in Javascript. The only way to access `Obj.bar` from `Obj.foo` is by direct reference.

```
var Obj = {
    foo: {
        foo: function () {
            return Obj.bar;
        },
        bar: "bar"
    },
    bar: "BAR"
}
```

Comment: your answer does not answer the question. Of course there are millions of ways to access `Obj` from other places, but there is NO WAY for an object to get reference to objects that hold a reference (the "owner" as the OP put it)  to it.